# What's the proper notation for a formula that includes values sampled from a distribution?

Tags: distributions, notation

I'm trying to write an equation for a time series $\text{TS}$ containing noisy and unevenly sampled data from a function $m(t)$. Here's what I've come up with:

$$\text{TS}(t \in \mathcal{U}(0, 1)) = m(t) + \mathcal{N}(0, 0.1) \quad $$

or maybe

$$\text{TS}(t) = m(t) + \mathcal{N}(0, 0.1) \quad t \in \mathcal{U}(0, 1)$$

but I fear that the $t$ part is incorrect because $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ is a distribution, not a set.

It's easy to program such an example, here's the code for example in python:

```
n_samples = 50
t_sample = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n_samples)
TS_sample = m(t_sample) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, n_samples)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is the $\sim$ relationship not what you're looking for? If so then that should probably be in your question for clarification.